# why am i getting the 'fatal error' msg when uploading photos within specified MB?

Tags: uploads

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16000 bytes). this is the message i'm getting trying to upload a 4.6MB photo, way under the 200MB max allowed. the photo is then appearing in Gallery, but i can't change size, the 'full size' circle is ticked and it won't come off that for thumbnail, medium etc. i've already uploaded similar size photos in 3 other posts successfully. does it mean i've reached my limit and can't use photos in any further posts?

can anyone help in non-techy speak?

Comment: This has something to do with PHP's `memory_limit` value set in `php.ini` and not WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

An image in memory takes often much [more space than on a disk](http://www.scantips.com/basics1d.html). The reason: images on a disk are compressed. To create new sizes or apply other changes to the image it has to be uncompressed and depending on color depth and compression algorithm.

There is no way to predict the real memory usage before the image is uploaded.

What you can do before upload:

- Reduce the color depth.
- Cut the image down to the maximal size you really need. Do not upload an image with a width of 2000 pixels if your maximal width is 900 pixel.